# Reason why this reinterpret_cast crashes

Tags: c++, crash, strict-aliasing

**Background:** I work a lot with binary data, and I often need to work with raw pointers. I also often need the size so that I can check if I read/write off the bounds (reasonable, right?). Now I'm trying to create a syntactic sugar class for pointers that holds size of the underlying data so that I can simplify function declarations.

**Demonstration of the problem** - the code behind my class that crashes can be simplified to this:

```
char *a = (char*) malloc(4); // some underlying data
strncpy(a, "1234", 4); // that is not statically linked so it can be written to

uint32_t *ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(a);

ptr[0] = 1234; // works
reinterpret_cast<int&>(ptr[0]) = 1234; // curiously, this works too
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr[0]) = 1234; // this crashes the program

printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
```

The program above crashes as described in comments. Valgrind outputs following:

```
Invalid write of size 4
   at 0x40064A: main (in /home/rr-/test)
 Address 0x4d2 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I suspect I'm violating the strict aliasing rule, but:

1. I made sure to use `char*` for underlying structure. Most likely, it doesn't matter because what I'm `reinterpret_cast`ing isn't a `char*` but a `uint32_t*` and compiler doesn't care what `uint32_t*` originally pointed at.
2. But even if I play with `-fno-strict-aliasing` and `-fstrict-aliasing`, the program crashes all the same... (I compile the program with g++ 5.2.0 under GNU/Linux.)

Can someone tell where did I go wrong, and how can I correct this problem?

Comment: What do you think `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr[0]) = 1234;` does?

Comment: Yeah, I realized it while I was commuting to work. What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just stored 1234 in `ptr[0]`. Then you cast the 1234 into a pointer and dereference it.

That tries to access address 1234, which doesn't work.